# Getting NullPointerException when trying to unit test kafka publisher controller

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, groovy, apache-kafka, spock

I am trying to test a controller that publishes in Kafka topic but my unit test keeps falling because I am getting null for kafkaTemplate.send().

**Controller class**

```
public class Controller {

  private final KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate;
  private final PublisherServices publisherServices;
  private static final String TOPIC = "Kafka publisher";

  @PostMapping("/publish_to")
  public String postTo(@RequestBody final RequestModel limitMessage)
        throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
     if(limitMessage.getCount() <= 0){
        return "your count is less than 0, there's nothing to be published!";
     }

     for (int countToBePublished = limitMessage.getCount();
       countToBePublished > 0;
       countToBePublished--) {
         log.info("publishing count  {} ", countToBePublished);
         kafkaTemplate
            .send(TOPIC, publisherServices.message(limitMessage))
            .get();
     }

     return "Published successfully to topic";
}
```

**Unit test for the Controller class**

```
//unit test
def "published the topic"() {

  def kafkaTemplateMock  = Mock(KafkaTemplate.class)
  def publisherServicesMock = Mock(PublisherServices)
  def controller = new Controller(kafkaTemplateMock,publisherServicesMock)

  given:
  def model = new RequestModel(1234, "2345", "topic" )
  def TOPIC = "Kafka publisher"

  when:
  Controller.postTo(model)
  def response = kafkaTemplateMock.send(TOPIC, model)
  kafkaTemplateMock.send(TOPIC, model)
  then:
  1 * controller.postTo(model)
  response == "Published successfully to topic"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your code.

1. You are trying to assert execution for a non mock `1 * controller.postTo(model)`
2. You treat `kafkaTemplateMock` as if it wasn't a mock.
3. `Controller.postTo(model)` this is a static invocation

Mocks return null by default, you need to [stub](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_stubbing) the return value, or if you are also asserting executions you need to combine [mocking and stubbing](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing).

Going from your code it could look like this:

```
def "published the topic"() {
  given:
  KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplateMock  = Mock()
  PublisherServices publisherServicesMock = Mock()
  def controller = new Controller(kafkaTemplateMock,publisherServicesMock)

  def model = new RequestModel(1234, "2345", "topic" )
  def TOPIC = "Kafka publisher"

  when:
  def response = controller.postTo(model)

  then:
  1 * kafkaTemplateMock.send(TOPIC, model) >> Optional.of("") // Here you need to return whatever the real method would return, as you haven't shared this part of the code, I assume Optional, as it has a get method, could also be a Future or anything else
  response == "Published successfully to topic"
}
```